# Front-end validation: Using a plugin vs writing it from scratch?

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

What are the pros and cons of using a plugin compared to writing the code yourself? I'm currently writing some validation from scratch, only because I find the plugins a bit confusing. They normally have minimal APIs (at least compared to raw JS or JQuery.)

Do most people use plugins or just write raw?

Comment: I tend to roll my own.  I use a convention-based approach that allows my custom control/components to self validate.  You have to code the rules somewhere, and it is generally leaner and just as quick for me to do it myself.  If you are a less comfortable with JavaScript, HTML/CSS, and jQuery, then a plugin may be helpful.

Comment: This question invites opinions rather than hard facts and therefore doesn't really fit on Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and [help/dont-ask] for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Apoligies, I'm new. I request removal.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow and I hope we can help you with a different programming problem soon!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity of what you are validating.  Also, jQuery is not the only library, you may want to invest some time in choosing a JavaScript library that fits your needs well.

Comment: I agree. I use Knockout or Angular, depending on the client's preference, along with jQuery and both offer significant advantages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing your own, as it is quite straight-forward.  See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/W4g4e/7/

The idea is to create an array which contains pairs of human "Field Titles" and element IDs, e.g.

```
arrAll = {'Field One':'f1','Field Two':'f2','Three':'f3','Four':'f4'};
```

Upon an error, the field title (e.g. "Field Two") is used in the error message to the user, and the element's ID (e.g. `$('#f2')` ) is used to focus on the element itself.